# Tons of log entries for Mail

Tags: mail.app, macos

I get tons of log entries from Mail.app as:

```
2014-10-17 09:41:07.059 Mail[344]: Received undocumented error: The meeting message couldn't be correlated because the target is a repeating master and the meeting message is an occurrence. on EWS response <MFEWSGetItemsResponseOperation: 0x7fb83169e9c0>{name = '(null)'} (EXECUTING)
2014-10-17 09:41:07.059 Mail[344]: Recieved EWS error: Error Domain=MFEWSErrorDomain Code=141 "The meeting message couldn't be correlated because the target is a repeating master and the meeting message is an occurrence." UserInfo=0x7fb836034860 {NSLocalizedDescription=The meeting message couldn't be correlated because the target is a repeating master and the meeting message is an occurrence.}
```

Sometimes up to 10-15 entries per second. Then it stops for a minute or so and begins again.

Is there a way to identify the message with the meeting information that is causing the problem?

Comment: I know you had no other responses here, but did you ever get this fixed? I see the same problem with OS X 10.10.2, talking with an Exchange 2010 server.

Comment: Not yet. I am still getting them, but on the other hand I have no other symptoms.